# удаление старых файлов с помощью find

Tags: linux

Нужно написать команду, которая бы удаляла все файлы расширения .txt из папки /home/u20806/public_html, которые были созданы или изменены 25 минут назад.

Сделал так: `find /home/u20806/public_html -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mmin +25 -type f -name "*.txt" \ -exec rm -f {} \;`

Выдает ошибку `find: path must precede expression:
Usage: find [-H][-L][-P][-Olevel][-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec][path...][expression]`

Как переписать?

Comment: попробуйте **find /home/u20806/public_html -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mmin +25 -type f -name "*.txt" | -exec rm -f {}**. если сработает - оформлю как ответ. чтобы некоторые лица очки репутации не снижали...

Comment: @alexander barakin упоминание cron **относится** к сукти вопроса. человеку нужно с этим разобраться

Comment: @alexander barakin у вас завзятое отношение к людям...

Comment: @alexander barakin просьба: перечитайте историю комментариев... с чего начали и чем закончили? такое поведение и есть предвзятость

Comment: @айтишник, я, кажется, понял причину недопонимания вами моих действий. дело в том, что [ru.so] — это, в первую очередь, [база знаний](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/173/178576), а помощь, которую получает человек, задавший вопрос — это как бы «приятное дополнение». именно в расчёте на тех, кто в будущем будет искать ответ про удаление файлов, я и сделал вопрос чуть более «каноническим», убрав не относящееся к работе программы `find` упоминание о программе `cron`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

я вижу в этой команде две ошибки и одну неоптимальность:

```
find /home/u20806/public_html -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mmin +25 -type f -name "*.txt" \ -exec rm -f {} \;
```

во-первых, благодаря опции `-daystart` программа `find` «найдёт» не совсем то, что вам требуется: время (указанное опцией `-mmin`) будет «отсчитываться» не от текущего момента, а от начала этого дня (см. внимательней на описание опции `-daystart` в `man find`).

во-вторых, параметр `\` между `-name` и `-exec` не нужен и порождает описанную ошибку.

в-третьих, и действие `-exec ...` лучше заменить на действие `-delete`.

резюмируя, предложу написать, например, так:

```
find /home/u20806/public_html -maxdepth 1 -mmin +25 -type f -name "*.txt" -delete
```

Comment: Чуть-чуть обогнали. Плюсую. Автор, используй `-delete`.